# Extract values from Regex Group

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a problem in which I need to be able to extract values from a string in a list.

I used re in a for loop to match a group pattern from each string in the list and assign it to a variable and print this on a line using the format method.

```
import re
inventory = ["shoes, 12, 29.99", "shirts, 20, 9.99", "sweatpants, 25, 15.00", "scarves, 13, 7.75"]

for items in inventory:
    pattern = "(?P<product>[a-z]+),\s(?P<quantity>[0-9]+),\s(?P<price>[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2})"
    details = re.match(pattern, items)
    
    product = details.group('product')
    quantity = details.group('quantity')
    price = details.group('price')
    
    print("The store has {} {}, each for {} USD".format(quantity, product, price))
```

Which yields me the results

```
The store has 12 shoes, each for 29.99 USD
The store has 20 shirts, each for 9.99 USD
The store has 25 sweatpants, each for 15.00 USD
The store has 13 scarves, each for 7.75 USD
```

I wanted to ask if it's possible to use `details.groups` to extract the values from the tuple and print the desired result or any advice to refine/simplify this?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `product, quantity, price = details.groups()`

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the regex if the format is this simple. Instead I would just use split like so: `product, quantity, price = items.split(", ")` or as a one-liner: `print("The store has {1} {0}, each for {2} USD".format(*items.split(", ")))`

Comment: It is just enough to remove `?P<product>` from the `pattern` and in the print use `.format(*details.groups())`. Do not forget to comment product, quantity and price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we can make your solution even more tight with the help of `re.split` and `f` strings:

```py
import re

inventory = ["shoes, 12, 29.99", "shirts, 20, 9.99", "sweatpants, 25, 15.00", "scarves, 13, 7.75"]
for inv in inventory:
    product, quantity, price  = re.split(r',\s*', inv)
    print(f"The store has {quantity} {product}, each for {price} USD"
```

This prints:

```
The store has 12 shoes, each for 29.99 USD
The store has 20 shirts, each for 9.99 USD
The store has 25 sweatpants, each for 15.00 USD
The store has 13 scarves, each for 7.75 USD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
print("The store has {quantity} {product}, each for {price} USD".format(**details.groupdict()))
```

Note that placeholders are named the same way as the regex named capturing groups.

The [following code](https://ideone.com/CMHLai):

```py
import re
inventory = ["shoes, 12, 29.99", "shirts, 20, 9.99", "sweatpants, 25, 15.00", "scarves, 13, 7.75"]
pattern = "(?P<product>[a-z]+),\s(?P<quantity>[0-9]+),\s(?P<price>[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2})"

for items in inventory:
    details = re.match(pattern, items)
    print("The store has {quantity} {product}, each for {price} USD".format(**details.groupdict()))
```

also prints

```
The store has 12 shoes, each for 29.99 USD
The store has 20 shirts, each for 9.99 USD
The store has 25 sweatpants, each for 15.00 USD
The store has 13 scarves, each for 7.75 USD
```

Note also that the `pattern` is defined outside of the `for` loop, for better performance.